# check datetime fails?

Tags: php

```
 function is_due($due_date)
        {
            $now=new DateTime('now');
            $dnow=$now->format('Y-m-d');
            $due=$due_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $interval =(strtotime($dnow)-strtotime($due));
        print_r($due_date->format('Y-m-d'));
        return $interval;
        }
```

i use that function to check if the given date is due

The $due_date is passed in after being retrieved from an external file as a string '2012-12-12' which is assigned as an array element, for example,

$datetime['due']=ReadExtFile();
When I call that function as `print_r(is_due($datetime['due']));` or

```
$due=new DateTime($datetime['due']);
```

nothing seems to work, I see no output. But `print_r($datetime)` will display the result of [due].

Comment: What happens if you do print_r(is_due($datetime))?

Comment: Ummm. why strtotime? `$interval = $now->getTimeStamp() - $due_date->getTimeStamp()`.

Answer (score 0):

The way this method is written, it expects $due_date to be a DateTime object, and not a string. You indicate you are passing in a string and not an object.

It looks like you just want to return $interval as a count of from the date given until now. I would suggest just using a simple method that only deals with strings.

```
function is_due($due_date) {
    return time() - strtotime($due_date);
    // return ((time() - strtotime($due_date)) >= 0); // depending on function you want this might work
}
```